# Do variables we declare inside the main() method of java , get instantiated as object?

Tags: java

What i'm asking is If i declare a data member inside the `main()` of a class in java will it be instantiated as an object buffer of an object of that class?
For example:

```
class Demo{

   int x=10;
   public static void main(String... s){

        int y=20;
        Demo d=new Demo();
    }
}
```

Here, will the `int y` be instantiated in the object `d` of class `Demo`. And if not, how is memory allocated to it ? Will it be considered as a local variable ?

Comment: You used varargs in your `main` header... I like you.

Comment: yes it will be local variable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, `y` is instantiated as a simple local variable on the stack in the `main` method, so it is only available in that scope. Like any other local variable, it will be destroyed when its scope exits, so in this case, `y` is destroyed when `main` exits.

Similarly, `d` is a local variable in `main`, but the *object* that it points to (a `Demo` object, in this case) is allocated on the heap. Just like any other object on the heap, it will be garbage collected when no other references point to it. In this case, of course, `d` is a reference pointing to it from inside the `main` method's local scope, so that object will only be garbage collected when `d` is no longer pointing to it (i.e. after `main` exits).

And then there's the extra complications added by multithreading, which make object lifetimes and such harder to reason about.

Answer (score 2):

A separate x will be instantiated per instance of Demo is created. A separate y is instantiated each time main runs.